# R: Using Arguments of One Function as Parameter for Another

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a custom function that has an arugment that requires the arguments of another function. For instance, something like this:

```
funct1 <- function(x,y,z){
   x + y + z
}

funct2 <- function(funct1, multiplier) {
  print("first arg is ": [funct1 x arg]
  print("second arg is ": [funct1 y arg]
  print("third arg is ": [funct1 z arg]
}

first <- funct1(1,2,3)
funct2(first1, 2) 
#first arg is 1
#second arg is 2
#third arg is 3

first <- funct1(3,4,5) #12
funct2(first1, 2) 
#first arg is 3
#second arg is 4
#third arg is 5
```

Comment: are you planning on changing variable values in `funct1()` or not? That fundamentally changes the answer.

Comment: yes, the values of ```funct1``` as I plan on assigning it to different objects. What I'm trying to do is make ```funct2``` dynamically depending on what is passed with ```funct1```. Hope this helps!

Comment: You really should have made that clear and then @Honey wouldn't have been led down the wrong path.

Comment: Apologies, I'm editing my question now after reading his comment.

Comment: So you either need to think more about what you're asking or give us more detail. Presently `funct1` takes three inputs and returns 1, yet you think that you're going to use them from that function. You're not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to pass the function and arguments into the new function without having to define what those arguments are then you can use `...`

```
f1 <- function(x, y, z){x + y + z}
f2 <- function(x, y){x * y}

doubler <- function(func, ...){
  func(...) * 2
}

f1(1, 2, 3)
# 6
doubler(f1, 1, 2, 3)
# 12
f2(3, 4)
# 12
doubler(f2, 3, 4)
# 24
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to have the same variable in each. What is the end game for this though?

```
funct1 <- function(x,y,z){
   x + y + z
}

funct2 <- function(x,y,z) {
  funct1(x,y,z) * 2
}

funct2(3,4,5)

> 24
```

Comment: Right, I guess I should specify that I'm trying to avoid having to put in the same arguments. I can just assign ```funct1``` to an object and then pass that along into ```funct2```

Comment: `funct2 <- function() {
  funct1(3,4,5) * 2
}`  
Will work, but I'm still not really sure why you would do this? You could just go `funct1(3,4,5) *2` you know?